# How to change the captions of Memoirs marginfigure?

Tags: memoir

I'm using the Memoir class, which provides the `marginfigure` float, to allow figures to be set in the margin. However I'm not completely satisfied with the typesetting of the spacing between the figure and the caption.

Setting the normal `abovecaptionskip` does not seem to affect the marginfigure captions.

I've also tried with commands similar to the below, without any luck.

```
\setmarginfloatcaptionadjustment{figure}{\vspace*{-20pt}}
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided a MWE to show what you have tried. You say you are not completely satisfied with the spacing between the figure and the caption. Is it too small, too large, too...?

Comment: Have you found a fix for the problem? I am having the same issue with memoir but I am not using the float package. The large skip above the caption only appears at pgfplots graphics. Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\begin{marginfigure}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt} % or whatever length suits you
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt} % or whatever length suits you
A MARGINFIGURE
\caption{The caption}
\end{marginfigure}
```

I have no idea whether you put your caption above or below your figure.

GOM

Comment: Yes, thanks. In the end the \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{} worked for me. 

The problem turned out to be a lot more involved than previously anticipated. It seems that I have a a weird combination of packages conspiring against me, in a way that I can't totally reproduce. Essentially I get an extra vertical spacing if I load the package `float` together with **something else**. I therefore temporarily (yeah, keep telling myself that) fixed it by doing `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-10pt}` in my marginfigures.

I might look into it more deeply when I've handed in my master thesis.